# MySQL Query Question to finde value in string

Tags: mysql

i have a simple (i hope its simple) question.
In my database, i have an entry like this:

[image]

Now, i need a response with true or a count if the '514' in 'error_code' is in the string 'count_alarm'. In this example it returns zero because 514 isnt in count_alarm.
I beginns the query, but i dont know how i can solve this query:

> select count(*) from table where sID='56df32a1463d4387' and [if
> error_code in count_alarm then True]

Somebody an idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: Normalize your schema. See ["Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (Spoiler: Yes, it is.).

Comment: thanks for the hint. i´ll check that.

Answer (score 1):

`find_in_set` can parse comma separated fields:

```
select count(*) 
from your_table 
where sID = '56df32a1463d4387' 
and find_in_set(error_code, replace(count_alarm, '|', ',')) > 0
```

or use `instr`

```
where sID = '56df32a1463d4387' 
and instr(count_alarm, concat('|', error_code, '|')) > 0
```

Comment: Works great, "instr" and "concat" are the magic words.... Thank you.

Comment: The first query should also work. I just added the missing `)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can just use `REGEXP` here:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE sID = '56df32a1463d4387' AND
      count_alarm REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', error_code, '[[:>:]]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(sID) as n514 from table where sID='56df32a1463d4387' 
and count_alarm like '%|514|%'
```

The **LIKE** operator searches for the pattern *|514|* anywhere in the value under count_alarm.

The assumption is that the first and last character of that value is this character *|* else 514 would not be found if it is the first or last pattern within that value.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.